# Align the elements in multiple rows horizontally

Tags: css

I'm developing a [webapp](http://koolbusiness.com) that generates a list of online classifieds. Now the small image is not properly aligned if you look at the first and second elements in the list:

[image]

```html
<div class="item">
    <abbr2 class="date dtstart value item_age" title="2013-05-07T12:48:07+0000">
        Today
        <br>13:23
    </abbr2>

    <a lang="" class="item_img" tabindex="1" href="/vi/5775056084926464.html">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jscy04U7d2qfgGe6PecBDv63HpzeNnIHn62_hk71A0yYM6Vdw7_OwcnaeCotDjMg4e7i07bJwdLgPhM7QlqW35HK=s65" title="Post Free Ads - List your advertisement" alt="Post Free Ads - List your advertisement">
    </a>

    <div class="item_info">
        <h3 class="item_subject">
            <a href="/vi/5775056084926464.html">Post Free Ads - List your advertisement </a>
        </h3>
        <!-- s -->
        <p class="item_teaser">Post Free Ads on top sites. ...
        </p>

        <div class="item_segments clean_links nohistory">
            <small>
                <a class="category" href="/q?query=category%3D6030+and+cityID%3D4691207+and+type%3Ds">
                    Services
                    <br>
                    For sale,
                    Madgaon, Goa</a>

            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item_price">
    <span class="price_span"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/1w9ecxvu/) with the problem.

Comment: Wrap the first two items inside a div and give it a width value.

Comment: Its basically because the first element is floating. So, as Manoj said, try adding 
#list_item_thumbs .item_age{
width:53px;
} to your code. And it shall fix this.

Comment: You are displaying tabular data, why not to use tables?

Comment: @Programmer400   the issue is with the price also so you should look out that thing also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a width

**CSS**

```
.date{
    width: 60px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1w9ecxvu/2/)**